# What Java Web framework to choose?

Tags: java, frameworks, dojo

Please help me to choose the most suitable Web framework for me and for the task I have to deal with.

The task: develop customer relationship management Web application for small and medium business with good performance.

Server side:
I'm an expert in Java, have never written anything on Groovy or Scala. Also, I have some experience in JSF (IBM portlets). The application server will be Tomcat, but we can switch to some other free server, if necessary.

Client side:
I used to create custom widgets with Dojo for developing rich Web applications. So, I call the server side with an XmlHttpRequest (dojo.xhrGet), on the server side I pack data into JSON, and then on the client side I deal with this JSON data inside my widgets. Debugging widgets takes rather much time. So, if there were something more developer-friendly (running with the same performance, that's important), that would nice.

Please advise.

Comment: I'd suggest backend with https://jersey.java.net which supports json and frontend with https://vaadin.com/home. Both pure Java

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This sort of question isn't really suitable, since there is not a clear single right answer.  Take a look at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ for more information.

Comment: @anvarik I've taken a look at Vaadin, I believe we'll loose too much performance with it

Comment: easy to use, but performance is an issue as u ve said ..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you should choose the technology bringing less risks for you.  If you consider yourself proficient with a JSF-Dojo combination, and have no non-functional requirements on the framework you must use... then use it.

Take profit of your know-how at work, then go home and spend some hours learning new technologies and acquiring new know-how on some technologies that make you feel curious :)

Comment: Hours only? You must be some kind of super-learner, I take at least two weeks to get out of the novice phase regarding technology that is less-than-trivial.

Comment: I've learned Spring a bit, currently looking at Spring MVC + Spring Roo,
JSF fits worse than Spring I guess, because:
- it's not convenient to work with url sending xhr to server side, and I have to create my own servlet to send requests to it
- I don't need all those JSF tags since I create content with my custom dojo widgets, and the only thing I use it for is storing logon info in session bean then

Comment: @ElijahK I actually like Spring MVC or Struts 2 better than JSF, I only wanted to say that you must choose whatever you feel more comfortable with, and since you had already mentioned JSF...  My choice would surely be Spring MVC + some javascript framework where I feel comfortable for presentation (in my case jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "The Java Web framework to choose". The framework you choose depends on many factors like:

- Use case
- Technical requirements
- (Organization) standards
- Performance
- Extendibility
- Community & support
- ...

Because of it, this question cannot be answered. There are simply too many factors and too many frameworks that will apply.